# Service Worker is failing causing Network error when the file is too big or speed is slow

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

I'm trying to make a simple download button to work with mock file data but, for some reason that I'm not aware of, I get a **Network Error**.

Basicaly what Im doing is requesting a specific file to a **service worker** that is prepared to pipe a **ReadableStream** as a response. This stream is filled with a simple character until it reaches 1gb of size.

> *Pseudo Code for the Service Worker* :

```
stream = new ReadableStream({
    start( ctrl ) {
        sharedMessageChannelPort.onmessage = ({data}) => {
            ctrl.enqueue(data);
        };
    }
});

/*...*/

event.respondWith( new Response( stream ));
```

> [Source Code](https://gist.github.com/poste9/34c96272f74a3fd98153179def8e2464)
>
> [**Working sample**](https://rawgit.com/poste9/34c96272f74a3fd98153179def8e2464/raw/e3ec61c588f0356d8aa839f071471e1284accbad/main.html)

---

Everything works fine until it suddently throws a Network Error and I have no idea what is going on.

I appreciate anything related that could help me at least understand why it's not working as I think it's supposed to.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the `NetworkError` triggered at the same point in time after every attempt? I.e. after X seconds? Or does it appear to be timed randomly?

Comment: completely random, only thing persistent is that it takes a while... never before 5 minutes.